# Англоязычные ресурсы для веб-разработчиков, в частности верстальщиков

Tags: jquery, html, css, php, javascript

Привет всем, собственно весь вопрос в заголовке. Хочется найти аналоги таких проектов как хабр, хтмлбук и прочее, мои поиски не довели до положительного результата :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://net.tutsplus.com/
- http://css-tricks.com/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/

Также неплохая [подборка для front-end'a](https://github.com/dypsilon/frontend-dev-bookmarks).

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow.com - сайт, по подобию которого был создан хэшкод.